# Помогите с функцией map в Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня есть состояние в нём хранится десять объектов у которых есть атрибут текст подскажите как вывести с помощью функции мап в эти тексты от 10 объектов

```
render(){
return (
    <ul>
      {this.state.Posts.map((Posts, i) => (<li key={Posts[i].id}  >{Posts[i].text}</li>) )}
      <br/>
    </ul>
)
};
```

это не работает выводит только текст первого объекта,заранее спасибо

Comment: Индекс не нужен в мап уже передается элемент массива почитай внимательно документацию
.map(elem => <li key={ elem.id }>{ elem.text }</li>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не правильно используете map, просто получайте аргументом текущий элемент и возвращайте модифицированный:

[Запустить на Codepen](https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/GXEOWR?editors=1010)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      Posts: [
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Hi'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'Bye'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div class="app">
        <ul>
          {this.state.Posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.text}</li>)}
          <br/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: спасибо большое илья все теперь работает <3